# Convert Array in Options

Tags: php, arrays

I need to convert an array as this:

```
$arrList =  Array
  (
    [0] => First Top element
    [1] => Second Top element
    [2] => Third Top element
    [Fourth Top element] => Array
      (
        [0] => Fourth Top element - A
        [1] => Fourth Top element - B
      )

    [3] => First Bottom element
    [4] => Second Bottom element
    [5] => Third Bottom element
    [Fourth Bottom element] => Array
      (
        [0] => Fourth Bottom element - A
        [1] => Fourth Bottom element - B
      )
  )
```

In options for my  list as this:

```
<option class="red">First Top element</option>
<option class="red">Second Top element</option>
<option class="red">Third Top element</option>
<optgroup label="Fourth Top element" class="red">
  <option>Fourth Top element - A</option>
  <option>Fourth Top element - B</option>
</optgroup>
<option class="green">First Bottom element</option>
<option class="green">Second Bottom element</option>
<option class="green">Third Bottom element</option>
<optgroup label="Fourth Bottom element" class="green">
  <option>Fourth Bottom element - A</option>
  <option>Fourth Bottom element - B</option>
</optgroup>
```

So I wrote this code:

```
foreach ($arrList as $element => $subelement) {
  $strClass = '';
  if(stristr('top',$subelement) || stristr('top',$element)) {
    $strClass = 'class="red"';
  } else if(stristr('bottom',$subelement) || stristr('bottom',$element)) {
    $strClass = 'class="green"';
  }

  if(!is_array($subelement)) {
    echo '<option '.$strClass.'>' . $subelement . '</option>'."\n";
  } else {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$element.'" '.$strClass.'>'."\n";
    foreach ($subelement as $elementLetter) {
        echo '<option>' . $elementLetter . '</option>'."\n";
    }   
    echo '</optgroup>'."\n";
  }
}
```

But it writes those:

```
<option >First Top element</option>
<option >Second Top element</option>
<option >Third Top element</option>
<optgroup label="Fourth Top element" class="red">
  <option>Fourth Top element - A</option>
  <option>Fourth Top element - B</option>
</optgroup>
<option >First Bottom element</option>
<option >Second Bottom element</option>
<option >Third Bottom element</option>
<optgroup label="Fourth Bottom element" class="green">
  <option>Fourth Bottom element - A</option>
  <option>Fourth Bottom element - B</option>
</optgroup>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: So your code works except for the correct classes?

Comment: `$strClass` is `''` and your if statement isn't triggering properly. You may want to use `stristr('top',$subelement,true)` to get whats BEFORE top because there is nothing after and even then I'm not sure if it will work because there is white space.

Answer (score 1):

So you're basically looking for something like this. The reason I don't use stristr is because it returns the part of the string following the part you were looking for. In this case, you don't want it. So why force the parser to make a copy of the string, cut it in parts, give it back to you... for you to just... throw it away without even looking at it. Instead, it's easier to use `strpos`, which returns the position where it found the string. If it didn't find it, it returns `false`. So a quick check for "is not false", is enough.

In case you really really need a case-INsensitive check, you can use `stripos`.

```
$list = array();
foreach($arrList as $key=>$el) {
   $class = '';
   if(strpos($el, 'top') !== false) {
      // top class
      $class = 'red';
   } else {
      // if not a top class, then it's bottom apparently
      $class = 'green';
   }
   if(is_array($el)) {
      if(strpos($key, 'top') !== false) {
         $class = 'red';
      } else {
         $class = 'green';
      }
      $list[] = '<optgroup label="'.$key.'" class="'.$class.'">';
      foreach($el as $subel) {
         $list[] = '<option>'.$subel.'</option>';
      }
      $list[] = '</optgroup>';
   } else {
      $list[] = '<option class="'.$class.'">'.$el.'</option>';
   }
}
$result = implode("\n", $list);
```